# How can I apply domain search paths to /etc/hosts lookups?

Tags: hosts, resolv.conf

I have a server with `search example.com` in resolv.conf, and it works correctly for DNS lookups. That is, if I ping `host`, and `host1.example.com` is in DNS, it is found.

But if `host1.example.com` is in /etc/hosts instead of DNS, it is not found. I assume the entry in resolv.conf only applies to DNS.

Is there a way to make a domain search path that works for /etc/hosts entries, and if not, why not?

Comment: You could have aliases in the hosts file, e.g. the entry `172.16.1.1 host1.example.com host1`.

Comment: You write ”*if I ping `host` […]*“. Don't you mean `host1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple and generally used method is to include both `host1` and `host1.example.com` to `/etc/hosts`.

However, you can reach your goal using `dnsmasq`. `dnsmasq` will read your hosts file (configurable,this is the default), you just have to set your original ns as upstream in dnsmasq and `localhost` as ns in `resolv.conf` and you can keep your search option. You will get the added benefit of locally cached name service.

This is the most basic (probably server) setup, if you are using resolvconf like ns manager you have to configure that instead.

It's worth to keep in mind, if you make changes in `/etc/hosts` you must restart `dnsmasq`.